# JGit unstaging files/removing files from the index and ammending a commit

Tags: jgit

I figured out how to do a lot of things in the JGit library, such as commit files, find out the status of all files (ie. changed, modified, untracked etc), but i can't figure out how to unstage files i added to the index.  Could someone let me know how to do this and maybe point me to some documenation as the eclipse site has none, and i can't find any on Google.

Also if anyone know how to ammend a commit i would much appreciate knowing that too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you found a way to unstage files but ran into trouble as explained in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803462/jgit-java-git-library-unstaging-files):

```
repository.getIndex().remove(getWorkignDirectoryAsFile(), new File(getWorkignDirectoryAsFile(), fileName));
repository.getIndex().write();
```

Did you solve your issue with the above? I notice that repository.getIndex() is deprecated and org.eclipse.jgit.dircache.DirCache should be used instead.

To amend a previous commit, you should look at

```
org.eclipse.jgit.api.CommitCommand.setAmend(boolean)
```

Would be great if you could report on your own answers if you found any.