# JGit Java Git Library Unstaging Files

Tags: java, git, jgit

I can't get reset to work properly in JGit.  Ie. i can add all files to the index, and i can remove/reset/unstage some of them from the index via the command below but it doesn't work for all files.  What is the proper way to unstage files in JGit?

```
repository.getIndex().remove(getWorkignDirectoryAsFile(), new File(getWorkignDirectoryAsFile(), fileName));
repository.getIndex().write();
```

Also

Comment: Are you getting any compile-time or runtime error?

Answer (score 4):

You can remove a file from the index using JGit `ResetCommand` class:

```
ResetCommand reset = new Git(repository).reset();
reset.setRef(Constants.HEAD);
reset.addPath("foo.txt");
reset.call();
```

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent of a plain `git reset` command is

```
git.reset().setMode(ResetType.MIXED).call();
```

Where `git` is an instance of `org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git` and `ResetType` refers to [`org.eclipse.jgit.api.ResetCommand.ResetType`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/3.5.1.201410131835-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/ResetCommand.ResetType.html)