# Remove files from staging area with JGIT

Tags: java, jgit

I need to do updates on the staged files list using the jgit libraries.

There is a method with jgit that can change the list of staged files (to remove some files from staging area to unstaged)?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use JGit to add deleted files to the index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32876426/how-can-i-use-jgit-to-add-deleted-files-to-the-index)

Comment: No, I actually want to remove the files from index.

Comment: This command works: git.reset().setMode(ResetType.MIXED).call(); (from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803462/jgit-java-git-library-unstaging-files)

Comment: This command: git.reset().setMode(ResetType.MIXED).call(); , It use to Remove all files from staging area? If I want just remove on file from staging area, How should I do it?